# Troubleshooting jQuery toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am trying to figure it out what I am doing wrong here. WP site, jQuery being loaded on the header, my custom jquery (main.js) is being loaded on the footer.

JQUERY:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery("#hc-register-toggle").click(function(){
        jQuery("#event-reg-form-group").toggle();
      });

    });
```

HMTL:

```
<a class="hc-float-left hc-main-button" id="hc-register-toggle">REGISTER NOW</a>

<div id="event-reg-form-groups">

    ..

    </div>
```

Trying to toggle the form when the button "REGISTER NOW" is clicked.

Any help would be appreciate. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typo here for missing 's' at end of Id. Use

`jQuery("#event-reg-form-groups").toggle();`

Also try changing the styling of button also. Whole button is not clickable once you hide the form. There is float related issue.

Comment: Thank you. That's an indicator to call the night.

Answer (score 1):

id you are using in your code is wrong. you have defined id as `event-reg-form-groups` and using as `event-reg-form-group`. try with this below code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("#hc-register-toggle").click(function(){
        jQuery("#event-reg-form-groups").toggle();
    });

});
```